# Search issue in SOLR when using wild card character

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene

This is the field type for the field name.

```
<fieldType name="myType" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The circuit name is `ABC123 XYZ456`.
When I search this using this wildcard search `*3 x*`, it's not working.
It looks like, I need to escape the white space using backward slash.

But I dont want to use escaping because it will involve lots of changes in the project.
So I tried this to escape the whitespace at query time in SOLR.

```
<fieldType name="myType" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\\s]" replacement="\\\\ " />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And its not working.

Do we have anything which can be done at the SOLR side without escaping at the project side so this document can be searched with `*3 x*`

Comment: Which query parser are you using?

Comment: Standard Query parser

Comment: which query you're using which doesn't work with spaces? could you give an example with proper solr syntax?

Comment: @Mysterion Here's an example Query -> entity-type:Circuit AND circuit-name-search:"*3 x*"

Comment: Nothing you do in the analyzer is going handle this. Spaces are part of query syntax, which is is parsed before analysis occurs. [ComplexPhraseQParser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser) would allow you to search for `circuit-name-search:"*3 x*"`, but if you just make a blanket change over to that query parser, good chance you'll screw up other searches in the process.